# Proper way of using django-storages with django-compressor on a multi-server setup

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage, django-compressor

I am trying to figure out how to use django-storages-redux together with django-compressor on a multi-server setup. All static files should be stored on Amazon S3 using boto.

**What I got so far**

Libraries used:

```
boto==2.38.0
boto3==1.2.3
botocore==1.3.18
Django==1.7.7
django-compressor==1.6
django-storages-redux==1.3
```

Important settings:

```
S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "-- REMOVED --"
S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "-- REMOVED --"

S3_DOMAINURL_FRT = "image.mydomain.com"
S3_BUCKETNAME_FRT = "image.mydomain.com"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = S3_BUCKETNAME_FRT
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = S3_DOMAINURL_FRT
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_S3_USE_SSL = False

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'site-static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'project.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATIC_URL = COMPRESS_URL = 'http://%s/' % S3_DOMAINURL_FRT

COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = 'cache'
```

"project.storage" Code:

```
import os
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class

os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'


class S3Storage(S3BotoStorage):
    @property
    def connection(self):
        if self._connection is None:
            self._connection = self.connection_class(
                self.access_key, self.secret_key,
                calling_format=self.calling_format, host='s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
        return self._connection


class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3Storage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        """ Always overwrite existing file with the same name. """
        name = self._clean_name(name)
        return name
```

**Problems**

Because we have multiple servers, we use COMPRESS_OFFLINE and run django-compress' *compress* command. This command generates the files locally on the server we ran the command from. Also a manifest.json is generated locally. Also because we use django-storages the local files are copied to S3. The manifest too. But now when trying to run django from another webserver, where these files are not present we run into errors like these:

```
You have offline compression enabled but key "677803469038e2efb349aad5ddc60c39" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

How can we compress our files on one server and let all the other servers use these files by linking to the S3 bucket? I think we somehow have to get the manifest.json file to all the other servers local filesystem?

Thanks alot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to set `COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD` to `'content'` in this application. 
[The compressor settings point this out](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS)